# Relocating shards in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

step 1) creating a node named "NODE1"

Step 2) creating new index in NODE1 named "application" and in index type as "testing"

step 3)index that created is with 5 shards. no replicas

Step 4)now i insert 5 doc in to index. it will splitted among 5 shards

Step 5)now i initiate new node called "NODE2"  in NODE1's Cluster.

Step 6) as per my understanding it shared shards between nodes. So my 2 shards moved to new node

Question 1)now i request document at NODE1 that is present in relocated shards(shards that moved from NODE1 to NODE2)

Question 2) Will my search return my requested document or not

Question 3) how does two nodes communicate each other

Question 4) Can i read and write in NODE2 ? if yes can i search same data written by NODE2 from NODE1..

Thanks in Advance..!

Comment: your question is not readable and no context. please try to redraft it

Comment: I updated my question..! sorry for inconvenience..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the answers are yes :)

The nodes communicate with each other through the transport port, by default 9300 port (or the first one free in the (9300-9400] range. They use a custom binary protocol to communicate, based on serialization of objects (not standard java serialization in most of the cases though).

Any node in a cluster is cluster-aware and knows where the shards are and so on, as they all share the so called cluster state. You can send requests (read and write) to any node and it will be rerouted to the interesting nodes and properly executed depending on the type of request.